# How to print correct number of rows in a table with Vue

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, vue.js

I"m just starting to learn Vue and I'm having a little issue printing out the correct number of rows I should be getting for a table.

My table has 2 columns and 4 expected rows.  When I test my code I get a table with 2 columns and one row with 4 column values using v-repeat or I get a table with 2 columns and 4 rows with the same information and 4 column values over 4 rows.

Basically trying to make a table that looks like this

```
       Col 1    |   Col2
row1   rData    |   rData
row2   rData    |   rData
row3   rData    |   rData
row4   rData    |   rData
```

The html

```
                      <table>
                          <thead id="tblHead">
                              <th v-for="item in items">
                                  {{ item.message }}
                              </th>
                          </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody id="tblInside">
                        <!--  <tr v-for="stuff in stuffs">
                              {{ stuff.message }}-->
                            <tr v-repeat="stuffsTD">
                              <td v-for="tdStuff in stuffsTD">
                                  {{ tdStuff.message }}
                              </td>
                          </tr>
                      </tbody>
                      </table>
```

The Vue.js

```
var tbl = new Vue({
    el: '#tblHead',
    data: {
        items: [
            { message: 'One' },
            { message: 'Two'}
        ]
    }
})

var inTbl = new Vue({
    el: '#tblInside',
    data: {
        stuffsTD: [
            { message: 'Row1 Col1 Plz' },
            { message: 'Row1 Col2 Plz' },
            { message: 'Row2 Col1 Plz' },
            { message: 'Row2 Col2 Plz' }
        ]
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this html:

```
                   <table>
                      <thead id="tblHead">
                          <th v-for="item in items">
                              {{ item.message }}
                          </th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody id="tblInside">

                        <tr>
                          <td v-for="tdStuff in stuffsTD">
                              {{ tdStuff.message }}
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>
                  </table>
```

Comment: That only creates 1 row with 4 columns.  I'm trying to only have 2 items per row.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out on my own.  Have to use v-for on the tr element

```
 <table id="tblData">
                             <thead>
                                 <tr>
                               <th v-for="column in columns">
                                 {{ column | uppercase }}
                                   </th>
                                  </tr>
                               </thead>
                           <tbody>
                           <tr v-for="tableData in tableData">
                              <td>
                                  {{ tableData.client }}
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                  {{ tableData.ad }}
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                  {{ tableData.rt }}
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           </tbody>
                        </table>
```

and

```
var tbl = new Vue({
    el: '#tblData',
    data: {
        columns: [ 'some', 'thing', 'here' ],
        tableData: [ 
            {
                some: 'A STORE',
                thing: 'Summer',
                here: '1:32'
            },
            {
                some: 'Computer Store',
                thing: 'fix',
                here: '2:14'
            },
            {
                some: 'Store 2',
                thing: 'MTG',
                here: '0:47'
            }
         ]
    }
})
```